# Regenerating values %random% after starting new process

Tags: batch-file

I am testing the following batch file as seen below. I always echo the value of num and number at the start of the bat just to check if these variable are empty. Which they are. On first run, the batch file gets to `echo Random number = %number%` and a valid number is shown. If the batch is then properly terminated by giving N as the choice, the batch closes. During the second start of the bat, a valid random number is chosen again as expect.

Unexpectedly, what occurs when a random number is chosen, and the batch file is ended by clicking the X or terminating the program with alt+f4. When starting the bat a second time, the random number chosen Most of the time be the same number that was chosen on the first run of the batch file. Even after `set "num="` and `set "number="` when `echo Random number = %number%` is ran the chosen number will be the same as the number chosen in the first ran bat.

I don't imagine this was explained very well, so perhaps the best way to see what is happening is to create and run the bat yourself. Chose a few random numbers during your first run through. Then force close the batch file and do not properly terminate the batch file. When you run the batch file again, the first chosen random number of run 2 will be the same random number last generated on run 1. Clearing the variable at the beginning of the bat file does not seem to resolve this problem. The question then is. How do I ensure that a new random number is always generated regardless of how the batch file is terminated? Is `set /a num=%random% * 10 / 32768 + 1` not the best way to set a random number?

```
@echo off
:start
set "num="
set "number="
echo old num=%num% and old number=%number%
pause
goto RAND
:RAND
cls
set /a num=%random% * 10 / 32768 + 1
set number=%num%
goto :%num%
:%num%
set "num="
echo Random number = %number%
echo.
CHOICE /M "Do you want another random number?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO exit
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO start
:exit
exit
```

Comment: Sure, the script is a bit difficult to write and it is nice! Specifically, after 10 milliseconds, for 30 times it will `echo !time! !random! !random! !random! !random! !random! !random!`. It is not so much difficult. Remove the `@echo off` at the top to see how it is interpreted. Also, I removed the `exit /b` in the `wait` subroutine to work fine with less time lost after each 10 milliseconds. BTW, I cannot understand **why** you need this code. Is there a specific reason? Are you trying to achieve something special? What is your whole code?

Comment: For "Specifically I don't understand:"...
the first line says "take one char from %time% at index 9 and assign it to a variable named 'last'
The second line says create a for loop from 1 to 30 and increment it by one each time.

Comment: @double-beep Thank you very much for the clarification. I am afraid the code isn't really meant for a practical use case. There is not need to post the code of what I am trying to do, so I'll just explain it. When the main .bat is ran, a random number number is assigned a variable. This variable is then used to start another external bat or program.. %num%.bat. The range I am using is 1-10 and each .bat file does something unique such as display a unique message. The problem was that if the process terminated, the same %num%.bat would always start. So no I can try to proper implement this.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you for the clarification. This information will help me learn a little more about how indexing works and used within batch.

Comment: You don't need to start a new batch file: add some `if` statements like `if %num% EQU 1 (do something)` or add subroutines named from 1 to 10 and consider them as small batch files. Add after the process of finding a random number a `goto :%num%` and you must be fine.

Comment: @double-beep So something like 
`goto :%num% 
:%num%
mycode`
Doesn't work. Variables are not supported in the Label. Adding 10 subroutines isn't very elegant.

Let me edit my original question, because I think I can has a more direct question for what I need answered.

Comment: This is not what I meant: you will have 10 subroutines with names like `:1`, `:2`, `:3`, etc. until 10. Let me take a look to the edited question for now.

Comment: @double-beep Yes I know this is what you meant. I implemented this, but it didn't solve the problem that is posted not so eloquently above.